# Create a conditional filter in JPQL query

Tags: spring-boot, jpql

I have two user roles and in my system, "ROOT" and "Simple User". In a certain page I need to execute diferents data filtering because "ROOT" can see all data and "Simple user"
only see a certain amount of their company's data. Here is the two queries for the filter:

```
///ROOT
"SELECT new com.data.dto.RelatorioFinaceiroDTO(r.id, r.dth_reserva, r.km_retirada,r.km_devolucao) FROM Reserva r WHERE  (r.dth_reserva >= :dtInicio AND r.dth_reserva <= :dtFim) AND r.veiculo.perfil=1 AND r.reserva.status=5 "

///Simple User

"SELECT new com.data.dto.RelatorioFinaceiroDTO(r.id, r.dth_reserva, r.km_retirada,r.km_devolucao) FROM Reserva r WHERE  (r.dth_reserva >= :dtInicio AND r.dth_reserva <= :dtFim) AND r.veiculo.perfil=1 AND r.reserva.status=5 AND r.veiculo.empresa.id = :empresaid"
```

The only diference between these two is the addition "r.veiculo.empresa.id = :empresaid" in the case of Simple User.

I want to create only one query with a conditional statemant for ":role"

I try this:

```
"SELECT new com.data.dto.RelatorioFinaceiroDTO(r.id, r.dth_reserva, r.km_retirada,r.km_devolucao) FROM Reserva r WHERE  (r.dth_reserva >= :dtInicio AND r.dth_reserva <= :dtFim) AND r.veiculo.perfil=1 AND (CASE WHEN :role!='ROOT' THEN r.reserva.status=5 AND r.veiculo.empresa.id = :empresaid ELSE TRUE END)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `CASE` this way, because logical tests in SQL (which JPQL ultimately translates to) do not have an intrinsic boolean value.

Try `AND :role = 'ROOT' or (r.reserva.status = 5 AND r.veiculo.empresa.id = :empresaid)`

In any case, it would be more readable to just have separate queries IMHO, or use a dynamic query building API like Criteria or QueryDSL.